# Multi authentication in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

How I do I implement multiple authentication in laravel 5.3. There is a package I used in laravel 5.2 called "sarav/laravel-multiauth" but according to the vendor, it does'nt work for 5.3. Is there any similar package i can easily use to implement multi auth where i can have admin and user guard() with different models?

Comment: See this document https://packagist.org/packages/sonars/multi-auth

Comment: Questions asking for links to off-site resources are off topic.

Comment: thanks @JewelFarazi thats exactly what i need

Comment: Thanks but how can give you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used [**sonars/multi-auth**](https://packagist.org/packages/sonars/multi-auth) and i got exactly what I wanted